# How do you animate a display object in an arc in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, math, physics

This is for a game in a flash AS3 only project.

the player controls a character with a gun.  By clicking on the screen the gun fires a missile in an arc to the point clicked.

Whats the best way to calculate the x and y co-ordinates of the missile for each frame?

Comment: this is not really an answer but maybe have a look at http://www.dl.ket.org/physicshon/chapters/03_1-3/. If you go down to the bottom is a flash activity teaching projectile motion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, an arc is a piece of a circle. The general formulas for a circle are

```
x = r * cos(a) + cx
y = r * sin(a) + cy
```

Where `r` is the radius of the circle, `a` is the angle along the circle (in radians), and `cx` and `cy` are the coordinates of the center of the circle.

So each frame you would increment the angle (`a`) and recalculate the position with those formulas.

The trick will be determining the appropriate radius and center points. You could probably figure out an algorithm that would find a center point based on a fixed radius.

Edit: To get the same velocity at different radii.

To get velocity (pixels/sec) from angular velocity (rad/sec)

```
v = Δa * r
```

So if we pick some `v`, then `Δa = v / r` where v is some constant and r is the radius of the circle.

Comment: How do you get a constant speed with different distances.  As I increase the angle at a constant rate the missile speeds up the further away it is?

Comment: ...it _shouldn't_ do that... Are you sure that your angle is increasing constantly? and that your angle is the only thing changing in the code?

Comment: If the circle diameter (distance) is bigger doesn't the missile have to travel further around the circumference for each angle increment?

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant a different angular speed at different points around the circle. I will add that info to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the missiles should fly in projectile rather than an arc path...

If you really care having a realistic motion, study [some physic equations](http://www.ajdesigner.com/phpprojectilemotion/vertical_velocity_equation.php).

If you just want to have some simple and cartoon-like motion, using [TweenMax](http://blog.greensock.com/tweenmaxas3/)'s bezier/bezierThrough will be extremely easy. See the examples in [its plug-in explorer](http://blog.greensock.com/tweenmaxas3/#fm_PluginExplorer_906666755).

---

Update:
For simple path tweening, [Grape Animation Library](http://blog.generalrelativity.org/actionscript-30/grape-animation-library/) seems great too!